# sqlite - Trigger - update after insert

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have two tables:

1. `Astro_temp1`, which contains header information from 100s of image files
2. `Astro_Target_Imaged_Date_Exposure`, which is a summary of information based on length of exposure time.

The `astro_target_imaged_date_exposure` table is created from temp table correctly: There are twelve rows in it which correctly represent image data from multiple days and multiple exposure times.
What I want to do is create a trigger/update that performs an update to `astro_target_imaged_date_exposure` after the row is inserted, which shall sum up the total exposure time for each row (total exposure time for all temp rows that match the insert).

I have tried a couple different methods, but it seems that it only performs the `sum(column name)` for the FIRST row inserted. It then applies that amount to every other row.

Currently this is how I have the update statement coded for the trigger.

```sql
    UPDATE astro_target_imaged_date_exposure
    SET 
    ATIDE_TotalExposure= (select sum(at1_exposure)
    FROM astro_target_imaged_date_exposure,
    astro_temp1
    where astro_temp1.AT1_Object = astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATI_TargetName
    and astro_temp1.AT1_TELESCOP = astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATI_Telescope
    and astro_temp1.AT1_FOCALLEN = astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATI_FocalLength
    and astro_temp1.AT1_SessionDate = astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATID_CCYYMMDD
    and astro_temp1.AT1_EXPOSURE = astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATIDE_Exposure_Amount
    group by astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATI_TargetName,
        astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATI_Telescope, 
        astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATI_FocalLength,
        astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATID_CCYYMMDD,
        astro_target_imaged_date_exposure.ATIDE_Exposure_Amount)
```

These are the table definitions:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE Astro_Temp1 (
        AT1_Object        TEXT,
        AT1_TELESCOP      TEXT,
        AT1_FOCALLEN      TEXT,
        AT1_ICAMERA       TEXT,
        AT1_GAIN          TEXT,
        AT1_GSCOPE        TEXT,
        AT1_GCAMERA       TEXT,
        AT1_MOUNT         TEXT,
        AT1_ROTNAME       TEXT,
        AT1_ROTATOR       TEXT,
        AT1_FOCNAME       TEXT,
        AT1_SessionDate   TEXT,
        AT1_FWHEEL        TEXT,
        AT1_FILTER        TEXT           DEFAULT RGB,
        AT1_EXPOSURE      NUMERIC (6, 2),
        AT1_DateLoc       TEXT,
        AT1_DateUTC       TEXT,
        AT1_UTC_OffSet    INTEGER,
        AEC_Constant_Name TEXT
    );

    CREATE TABLE Astro_Target_Imaged_Date_Exposure (
        ATI_TargetName             TEXT           NOT NULL,
        ATI_Telescope              TEXT           NOT NULL,
        ATI_FocalLength            TEXT           NOT NULL,
        ATID_CCYYMMDD              TEXT           NOT NULL,
        ATIDE_Exposure_Amount      NUMERIC (6, 2) DEFAULT (0),
        ATIDE_Filter               TEXT,
        ATDE_TotalApprovedExposure NUMERIC (6, 2) DEFAULT (0),
        ATIDE_TotalExposure        INTEGER        DEFAULT (0),
        ATIDE_Exposure_High_HFR    NUMERIC        DEFAULT (0),
        ATIDE_Exposure_Low_HFR     NUMERIC        DEFAULT (0),
        ATIDE_Approved_High_HFR    NUMERIC        DEFAULT (0),
        ATIDE_Approved_Low_HFR     NUMERIC        DEFAULT (0),
        PRIMARY KEY (
            ATI_TargetName,
            ATI_Telescope,
            ATI_FocalLength,
            ATID_CCYYMMDD,
            ATIDE_Exposure_Amount,
            ATIDE_Filter
        )
    );
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Please post the actual `CREATE TABLE` and relevant `CREATE INDEX` DDL statements instead of images.

Comment: I have added the ddl for the create table for both tables.  I never created an index for either table.  Is that why I am getting this type of behavior?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @OldAndRetired, I took liberty in editing your question for language and clarity; you may want to check if it still portrays your question accurately.

Comment: @OldAndRetired, it's not exactly clear what your expectations are here. The trigger as currently written will overwrite all `ATIDE_TotalExposure`-values for all rows in `astro_target_imaged_date_exposure`. That is because the `UPDATE` is not restricted with respect to which rows it should apply. Maybe you forgot a `WHERE`-clause, using the [`NEW`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) row's primary key (or whatever) to specify which rows should be updated?!

Comment: That was actually my first try.  I used a where clause on the update statement(temp column = , but then only one row was updated. and the sum ended up totallying every temp row that matched the where statement.  I found that when I didn't use the group by, that is what happens.  If I run that select statment only, it will break out the totalls correctly.  This was the only way I could figure out how to use the order by in an update statement.